# Как сделать ограничение на использование целей аннотации?

Tags: java

Заметил в api где используются аннотации есть некий ограничитель на использование определённых целей аннотаций.

Скажите пожалуйста, как это реализуется.

Например:
Использовать цель *password* нельзя, если отсутствует цель *user*

Работает:

```
@User(username = "root", password = "123456")
public static void addUser() { }
```

Не работает:

```
@User(password = "123456")
public static void addUser() { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется вы не с той стороны смотрите на проблему. Ограничитель - не то слово, которое правильно описывает ситуацию.
Смотрите на это с точки зрения обязательных/необязательных полей.
Так, для вашего примера существует обязательное поле username и необязательное password

В итоге при создании аннотации имеем следующую ее реализацию:

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target(value=ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface User {
     String username();
     String password() default "";
}
```

Мы определили дефолтное значение для password ключевым словом default (в данном случае это пустая строка, но при необходимости там может быть любое строчное значение), тем самым сделали password необязательным, а username напротив обязательным.

Теперь все работает именно так, как ожидалось.

Данный код работает:

```
@User(username = "root", password = "123456")
public static void addUser() { }
```

А этот код уже нет:

```
@User(password = "123456")
public static void addUser() { }
```

Comment: Здесь важно само решение, я хочу найти вариант с построением логических конструкций на основе целей аннотации, например: @Example(value = "class", name = "Main"); если @Example(value = "method", name = "equals", parameters = "Object"); (цель parameters становится обязательной).

Comment: @Deus судя по примеру, вы хотите в первом случае прицепить аннотацию на класс, а во втором - на метод. в этом случае вам нужны просто разные аннотации с разным Target. точно так же и с различными сложными вариациями параметров вам нужны разные аннотации